# C++ std_map doesn't iterate self-defined datatype

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, std

First of all, I defined my own memory allocator, MyAllocator.
Then I define my own map based on std::map with my own memory allocator:

```
template <typename K, typename V, typename Comparator = std::less<K>>
using MyMap = std::map<K, V, Comparator, MyAllocatorAdapter<std::pair<const K, V>>>;
```

So the usage will be:

```
MyMap<std::string, float> my_map(std::less<std::string>(), allocator);

my_map["key1"] = 10.1
my_map["key2"] = 10.2
my_map["key3"] = 10.3
```

Here MyMap works perfectly, [], inline functions, iterator, etc, just like std::map. Good!

Then I define my own type, MyString, which also works perfectly.

```
class MyString{
  ...define operators[], =, !=, find(),substr(), etc
}
```

But when I use it as the key in MyMap, come with problems!

```
MyMap<MyString, float> my_map(std::less<MyString>(), allocator);
MyString my_string="key1";
```

Most functions like [], functions, iterator fails!

I debug into the program and found in

```
`/user/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_mpl.h`,
```

iterator doesn't move.
Notice that std::less<> will eventually call MyString operator !=, I'd implement this function and no problem with that.
I was stuck and debug the problem for 2 days! Need help! thanks!

Comment: I'm not convinced that `std::less` will "eventually call MyString operator !=", as you say.  How is it even possible to determine which of two strings is *less* just using `!=`?

Comment: Read up on "strict weak ordering"

Comment: I had implement <, which calls !=

Answer (score 4):

`std::less` calls `operator<`. You need to implement that.

Comment: Sorry to mis-described in my original post, I'd implemented MyString's operator <, which actually call !=

Comment: @MartinGGWW That's bad, such `operator<` must abide by the rules of [strict weak order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering) - which your operator fails to provide (for example, if `a < b` is true, then `b < a` must be false).